# Using Liquid as a Ruby on Rails layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid-layout

I want to create a [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) layout and it should be in [Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) format.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to let the users to create their own layouts and save them in the database.

I tried to use 
`<%= Liquid::Template.parse(<code from database>).render %>` in my layout.erb file but there I can't use the 'yield' command (since this is a layout I should have to have a way of rendering pages.)

But when I use 'layout.liquid' with `{{ content_for_layout }}` is will work find BUT, cannot load details from the database (I mean the HTML code..)

I hope I made myself clear :D )

Comment: @sameera207: is "Liquid" as in http://www.liquidmarkup.org/ ? Or is it an adjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) plug-in:

http://github.com/akitaonrails/dynamic_liquid_templates

Next we have to find a way to intercept the default Ruby on Rails behaviour for your controller.

```
class MyAwesomeController
  layout :get_my_db_layout
  ....
  protected
  def get_my_db_layout
    'as_if_by_a_miracle.liquid' # add your db finder here        
  end
end
```

Then, overwrite `LocalFileSystem#read_template_file` with your own class / method, to get the template from the database. `LocalFileSystem#read_template_file` is a Liquid class.

I hope, that this idea is helpful.

Comment: sameera207 did this solve your problem for you? I'm trying to use it right now and getting the noodle wrapped around how akita used layouts to render this stuff is hurting my head right now.  any updates or a blog post would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

please read Tobis article on

https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/getting-liquid-to-work-in-rails

or look at this screencast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid

Comment: Hi crazyrails,

thanks for your reply. But my question remains :( , coz I want to keep my layout code in the database. (Ex: <html> .. </html>)

But my problem is , since rails layout has <%= yield%> method, i cant do it in my layout.erb file

A;m I doing something wrong here, or is there any alternative thanks again..

Comment: Maybe - this is what you want: Build a controller with an index action. In the controller you have to put all the Liquid::Template.parse(<code from database>).render things an assign it to a @output variable. In the index view call <%= @output %>.