# ruby on rails with liquid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.1 .

I am trying to use liquid . My file names are views/users/index.html.liquid

I am looking for a good documentation/blog or a working cms etc to see how to make it work.

I need to make rails aware of .liquid template and such things.

Comment: Would love to know this as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Liquid as a Ruby on Rails layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001298/using-liquid-as-a-ruby-on-rails-layout)

Comment: I found this very helpful:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about using Liquid with Rails in [RailsCast #118 Liquid](http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid).

Shopify also has this [wiki entry](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/getting-liquid-to-work-in-rails) on getting Liquid to work in Rails.

Answer (score -1):

You can start learning from this tutorials:

1. [rubyplus](https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/3761-Liquid-Template-in-Rails-5)
2. [ruby-journal](http://ruby-journal.com/liquid-template-in-ruby-done-right/)
3. [richonrails](https://richonrails.com/articles/liquid-templating-engine)